# Programmatically add Custom Product Attribute to attribute set

Tags: magento-1.9, php, attribute-set

Is there a way to add a custom Attribute (DB-Column, whatever) to product attribute sets?

I tried the following but it I get the error 'Wrong Entity ID':

```
/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup $this */
$this->addAttribute('eav/entity_attribute_set', 'pim_id', array(
    'group'         => 'General Information',
    'input'         => 'text',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'PIM ID',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => false,
    'required'      => false,
    'is_unique'     => true,
    'visible_on_front' => false,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));
```

Comment: check this link : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46358/add-custom-attributes-to-custom-attribute-set-programmatically

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php  
$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'pim_id', array(
            'group'           => 'General',
            'label'           => 'PIM ID',
            'input'           => 'text',
            'type'            => 'varchar',
            'required'        => 0,
            'visible_on_front'=> 1,
            'filterable'      => 0,
            'searchable'      => 0,
            'comparable'      => 0,
            'user_defined'    => 1,
            'is_configurable' => 0,
            'global'          => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'note'            => '',
));
$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

**Dropdown input with options**

```
<?php  
$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'addtocart_settings', array(          
            'group'                 => 'General',
            'label'                 => 'Add To Cart Settings',
            'input'                 => 'select',
            'type'                  => 'varchar',
            'required'              => 0,
            'visible_on_front'      => false,
            'filterable'            => 0,
            'filterable_in_search' => 0,
            'searchable'            => 0,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
            'comparable'      => 0,
            'user_defined'    => 1,
            'is_configurable' => 0,
            'global'          => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'option'          => array('values' => array('Default', 'Available at authorized dealer','Not available yet')),
            'note'            => ''
));

$installer->endSetup(); 

?>
```

Comment: Can you provide info about in which attribute set this attribute will be added?

Comment: It is added default attribute set

Comment: If need to add your custom attribute set then add code 

$installer->setAttributeSetId('catalog_product','Custom Attribute Set Name','General','pim_id');

for eg.$installer->setAttributeSetId('catalog_product','Watches','General','pim_id');

Comment: This works nicely. But unfortunatelly I can't filter by this field or is `Mage::getModel(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::class, ...)` the wrong class?

Comment: try this : $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
      ->addAttributeToSelect('pim_id');

Comment: @Abdul How would I add a dropdown input with options instead?

Comment: @Vaishal Patel Please check updates ans.

Comment: @abdul thanks. How can I add to inventory tab instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup $this */
$this->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'pim_id', array(
    'group'         => 'General Information',
    'input'         => 'text',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'PIM ID',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => false,
    'required'      => false,
    'is_unique'     => true,
    'visible_on_front' => false,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));
```

Comment: Can you provide info about in which attribute set this attribute will be added?

Comment: It will be added in all attribute set when it will created.

Answer (score 0):

Ref this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/162598/3506),

```php
$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
```

the `$installer` would not update the additional table `catalog_eav_atttribute`. That means fields such as `visible`, `searchable`, `filterable`, etc. would all be set to the default value. Instead, it should be

```php
$installer = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup('catalog_setup');
```